# Spring Security Oauth Issue

Tags: spring, security, oauth, spring-security

I have implemented Spring Security Oauth in my project.

I have 2 different modules in my project :

```
Module A
Module B
```

I have implemented my Oauth configurations in `Module A` using the XML definitions.  This is working successfully and I am able to generate access token and refresh token successfully when hitting the url : `/oauth/token`

Now `module B` is having dependency (defined in `pom.xml`) on `module A`. When I am trying to hit `/oauth/token` from module B : its giving me following exception :

```
InsufficientAuthenticationException:
                    There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.
```

This occurs in `TokenEndpoint`  in line 74 when following condition is true :

```
!(principal instanceof Authentication)
```

Can someone guide me what can be the issue and how could I resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Jubin